# How to syncronize events from google calendar to iPhone calendar

Tags: swift, calendar

I am trying to develop an app in which I need to synchronize google calender events with iPhone calender and vice versa (phone calendar with google calendar). I have gone through many site but I didn't get much help from it.

How can I synchronize events from Google calender to phone calender and phone calendar to google calendar.

I have used google documentation code to fetch events from google calender. The code I used is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let kKeychainItemName = "Google Calendar API"
    private let kClientID = "956493608063-qco5hl5a4ru3lffvbs88m51i1lokou03.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    private let kClientSecret = "txhI0fpL-9wKyl_A-6SnRvoI"

    private let scopes = [kGTLAuthScopeCalendarReadonly]

    private let service = GTLServiceCalendar()
    let output = UITextView()

    // and initialize the Google Calendar API service
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        output.frame = view.bounds
        output.editable = false
        output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
        output.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight |
            UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth

        view.addSubview(output);

        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(
            kKeychainItemName,
            clientID: kClientID,
            clientSecret: kClientSecret
        )

    }

    // When the view appears, ensure that the Google Calendar API service is authorized
    // and perform API calls
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let authorizer = service.authorizer,
            canAuth = authorizer.canAuthorize where canAuth {
                fetchEvents()
        } else {
            presentViewController(
                createAuthController(),
                animated: true,
                completion: nil
            )
        }
    }

    // Construct a query and get a list of upcoming events from the user calendar
    func fetchEvents() {
        let query = GTLQueryCalendar.queryForEventsListWithCalendarId("primary")
        query.maxResults = 10
        query.timeMin = GTLDateTime(date: NSDate(), timeZone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone())
        query.singleEvents = true
        query.orderBy = kGTLCalendarOrderByStartTime
        service.executeQuery(
            query,
            delegate: self,
            didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:"
        )
    }


    var eventsname:[String] = [String]()

    // Display the start dates and event summaries in the UITextView
    func displayResultWithTicket(
        ticket: GTLServiceTicket,
        finishedWithObject events : GTLCalendarEvents,
        error : NSError?) {

            if let error = error {
                showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            var eventString = ""
            var testing = ""

            if events.items().count > 0 {
                for event in events.items() as! [GTLCalendarEvent] {
                    var start : GTLDateTime! = event.start.dateTime ?? event.start.date
                    var startString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(
                        start.date,
                        dateStyle: .ShortStyle,
                        timeStyle: .ShortStyle
                    )


                    testing = "\(startString) - \(event.summary)"
                    eventString += "\(startString) - \(event.summary)\n"

                    eventsname.append(testing)                        
                }
            } else {
                eventString = "No upcoming events found."
            }

            //output.text = eventString
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let nextView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Display") as!DisplayViewController
            nextView.events = eventsname
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)

    }


    // Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google Calendar API
    private func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch {
        let scopeString = " ".join(scopes)
        return GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(
            scope: scopeString,
            clientID: kClientID,
            clientSecret: kClientSecret,
            keychainItemName: kKeychainItemName,
            delegate: self,
            finishedSelector: "viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:"
        )
    }

    // Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Google Calendar API
    // with the new credentials.
    func viewController(vc : UIViewController,
        finishedWithAuth authResult : GTMOAuth2Authentication, error : NSError?) {

            if let error = error {
                service.authorizer = nil
                showAlert("Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            service.authorizer = authResult
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Helper for showing an alert
    func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertView(
            title: title,
            message: message,
            delegate: nil,
            cancelButtonTitle: "OK"
        )
        alert.show()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }       
}
```

Now I have the google calender events and need to synchronize it with mobile caleder (and also want to synchronize my mobile calender events with google calendar).

Thank You.

Comment: For your security you should remove the ClientSecret.

Comment: Have you got this? I am also using this code to sync google events, but I am not getting the recurring ones.

Comment: Did you delete any event/reminder programmatically ? Please help me the way you did that. thanks.